# Запретить локальному компьютеру подключаться к любому компьютеру в сети

Tags: сеть

Предположим, у нас есть локальная сеть, в которой IP-адреса компьютеров:
192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.3, 192.168.1.4, 192.168.1.5, 192.168.1.6 и Требуется, чтобы, например, все остальные компьютеры   не могли подключиться компютеру с адресом 192.168.1.4. Как это сделать, если наша локальная сеть единая - все компьютеры работают под управлением обычной операционной системы Windows 7.

Comment: "все остальные компьютеры с адресом 192.168.1.4" - у Вас может быть несколько компов с одним айпи? В любом случае - хотите, что бы к машине не могли подключится - выдерните сетевой шнурок.

Comment: «все остальные компьютеры с адресом 192.168.1.4 не могли подключиться» — что именно подразумевается под этой фразой?

Comment: Вам нужен свитч с функцией traffic segmentation.

Comment: не могли подключиться компютеру с адресом 192.168.1.4

Comment: Поставьте личный роутер.

Answer (score -2):

Для ограничения сетевых соединений можно использовать фаэрволл.

Для личного использования наиболее подходящий бесплатный [GlassWire](https://www.glasswire.com/).

Если в нем не разберётесь, из бесплатных есть довольно простой [Evorim](https://www.evorim.com/en/free-firewall).

Если вы доверяете платным проприетарным решениям, есть надежный израильский проверенный двумя десятками лет [Zone Alarm](https://www.zonealarm.com/).

А если, например, вы захотите контролировать сетевой трафик на роутере, то однозначно решения лучше [OPNsense](https://opnsense.org/) не найти.

Если вы не доверяете компьютерам внутри локальной сети, для безопасности соединения подключайтесь к интернету через VPN.

Например, эти бесплатные: [calyx](https://calyx.net/), [riseup](https://riseup.net/ru/vpn).

Если бесплатные VPN для ваших задач медленные, тут https://openrunet.org/vpn.html можно подыскать недорогое решение.

Пока компьютер будет подключен к VPN, никто из локальной сети перехватить данные не сможет.

Также есть несколько дельных советов по безопасности от [Роскомсвободы](https://safe.roskomsvoboda.org/).

Если вы понимаете базовый технический английский язык, то на этих ресурсах вы найдёте очень много по-настоящему надёжных инструментов:

- https://www.privacytools.io/
- https://prism-break.org/ru/

Comment: серьезно? у него что, айпишник при этом пропадет?

Comment: @KoVadim или почему, например, для расшаривания vpn-соединения нужна вторая сетевая карта? https://support.nordvpn.com/Connectivity/Windows/1047409882/Sharing-a-VPN-connection-through-an-Ethernet-cable.htm

Comment: если у Вас возник вопрос - оформите его как вопрос

Comment: @DiD, по первому — не понятно, какая именно у OP'а в текущем посте ситуация, но ничего общего с вопросом по ссылке у него явно нет (ни какого разговора об удалённом доступе)... со вторым — тоже самое + это проприетарный сервис для хомячков и они не хотят описывать относительно сложную конфигурацию маршрутов для случая с одним интерфейсом...

Comment: @KoVadim вопрос сформулирован https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1195688/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d1%85-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be