# Как можно пользоваться ресурсами локальной сети (в обоих направлениях), когда компьютер подключен к ProtonVPN?

Tags: сеть, маршрутизация, vpn

У меня есть Macbook c OS Catalina, который подключен к интернету через мобильный Wifi-модем DIGMA DMW1969-WT. При этом, большую часть времени (всегда) на макбуке включен ProtonVPN с дефолтной конфигурацией.

1. Возможно ли, не выключая ProtonVPN, залезть в админку модема, чтобы, например, посмотреть баланс на симкарте?
2. Если к wifi-модему подключены другие компьютеры, могу ли я подключаться к ним с макбука по протоколам http/ftp/ssh, не выключая ProtonVPN?
3. Если к wifi-модему подключены другие компьютеры, могут ли они подключаться к макбуку по протоколам http/ftp/ssh, когда на макбуке включен ProtonVPN?
4. Если к wifi-модему подключены другие компьютеры, могу ли я с макбука раздать соединение через ProtonVPN для них? Или необходимо оплачивать VPN для каждого компьютера отдельно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Скорее всего да. Но бывают разные vpn. Надо смотреть в таблицу маршрутизацию, которую прописал впн клиент. А бывает, что vpn подымает сеть такую же, как и внутренняя и тогда могут быть проблемы. или перетрет под себя. Посмотрел в документацию. Похоже нужно поднастривать https://protonvpn.com/support/vpn-bypass-macos/ - там есть инструкция, как это сделать.
2. Ответ такой же.  роутер ничем в данном случае не отличается от других машин в Вашей сети.
3. Да, если они могли подключатся к нему до этого. Правда надо смотреть, не поднял ли в тихую этот клиент какой то фаервол. Тогда все может быть очень по другому.
4. да, можно. И есть много разные способы. Самый простой способ - поднять прокси (подойдет почти любая http/socks) на своей машине, а другим дать параметры для подключения. Если у Вас роутер с поддержой vpn внутри, можно настроить vpn прям там - https://protonvpn.com/support/vpn-router-ddwrt/ или https://protonvpn.com/blog/setup-a-vpn-router/

Но лучше заплатите. Так надежнее будет:) В любом случае, если Вы купили впн у них, всегда можно спросить у поддержки

Comment: Клиент опенсурсный. Врятли он что-то поднимает, чего нет в исходниках. Бинарники подписанны ключем AppleID. https://github.com/ProtonVPN/mac-app

Comment: В самом роутере адаптированная под Россию опенсурсная прошивка https://openwrt.org/ но ссылка в исходниках www.x-wrt.org (видимо, домен продается)

Comment: добавлю, что т.к. под капотом там обычный openvpn, то (1)—(3) вообще должны работать из коробки (но таблицу маршрутизации и конфиг openvpn'а надо всё же посмотреть, чтобы убедиться), а (4) я бы сделал, включив ip_forwarding на Macbook'е (похоже [вот так](https://serverfault.com/questions/97117/how-do-i-enable-ip-forwarding-in-macos-x)) и установил бы его шлюзом по умолчанию для всех других устройств... если ребята из ProtonVPN не делают какую-нить бяку вроде анализа ttl на своей стороне (как наши мобильные операторы), то всё должно заработать сразу...

Comment: Чип там в модеме Atheros AR9331-AL3A. Характеристики удручающие 4Мб flash/32Mb RAM. Прошивка с горем пополам идет, но модуль vpn она не потянет.

Comment: может тогда проще купить нормальный роутер?

Comment: @KoVadim какой например?

Comment: я пользуюсь микротиком, но это на ценителя. TP-Link вроде нормальные, но для разработчика может оказаться препятствием (у меня не работал на нем ssh через vpn, это было давно, я не разбирался детально, но похоже он mtu как то занижал). Ещё Asus неплохие вроде и vpn могут легко внутри поднять.